# java embedded derby table/view

Tags: java, derby, embedding

I created Embedded Derby database it give me error.although I have APP schema in which table REST created

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'REST' does not exist.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
```

here is java class:

```
public class Main
{   
    private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:tes;create=true";
    private static String tableName = "REST";
    // jdbc Connection
    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static Statement stmt = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        createConnection();
       insertRestaurants(5, "LaVals", "Berkeley");
        selectRestaurants();
        shutdown();
    }

    private static void createConnection()
    {
        try
        {
         // System.setProperty("derby.system.home", "/Users/myuser/futbol");
          Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            //Get a connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            except.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
     private static void insertRestaurants(int id, String restName, String cityName)
    {
        try
        {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("insert into REST values (" +
                    id + ",'" + restName + "','" + cityName +"')");
            stmt.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlExcept) 
        {
            sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I am four years behind on this, but I finally found out how I resolved my problem (hence why I am on this thread).

I created my table using the database script editor. I used double quotes around my table. I found this out when I went to the service tab (netbeans), and right clicked on my table to view data. I got this:

```
select * from {schema}."{table}"
```

So, I thought I would translate that to my java. And, Bingo.
Hopefully this will shed some light on your application, I copied and pasted some of your code and hopefully this will work.

```
public class Db {
    private final String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/{db}";
    private final String tab = "{schema}.\"REST\"";

    private static Connection createConnection() throws Exception {
         Connection conn = null;
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
         return conn;
    }

    private static void insertRestaurants(int id, String restName, String cityName)
    {
        try
        {
            Connection conn = createConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("insert into " + table + " values (" +
                    id + ",'" + restName + "','" + cityName +"')");
            stmt.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlExcept) 
        {
            sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Table names are case sensitive. Make sure the table you created is actually called "REST" with all caps or if it's "Rest" or "rest".

Comment: yes BOTH ARE UPPER CASE BUT STILL GIVE ME SAME ERROR ALTHOGH IT WORKS FINE WHEN I RIGHT CLICK IN db and select execute command.but in java it gives this error.

Comment: Table names are only case sensitive when they are created using double quotest. At least that's what the standard requires and as far as I know Derby complies with the standard there

Comment: Thanks for this comment!  I didn't realize tables were case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble with embedded db and finally cleared the same .This will help you for sure [aparna-java.blogspot.com](http://aparna-java.blogspot.com/2011/11/good-day-all.html) please check this

Answer (score 0):

A simple example @ http://javabyranjith.blogspot.in/2016/08/apache-derby-with-java-example.html. Hope it can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I did the following fix, using Eclipse:

(In Database Perspective: Window>Perspective>Open Perspective>Other>Database Development), right clicking Database Connection folder>New>Derby:

You have to make sure the 'Database Location' folder is at the same location as the Derby.jar location mentioned at (Edit Driver Definition>JAR List). Like see below snapshot:

[Derby Jar Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG0lY.jpg)

[Derby DB Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXJzN.jpg)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You might find it easier to learn Derby by starting with the Derby tutorials: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/getstart/cgstutorialintro.html